# Target Shortcut for PowerShell keeps rewriting

Tags: powershell, shortcut, target

I want to run a PowerShell script from a shortcut. I am running Windows 10. According to $PSVersionTable.PSVersion I am running version 5.1 of PowerShell.

In my Target I type the following:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\myname\directory\search5.ps1
```

FYI, search5.ps1 is a 2 line script:

```
$text=(Get-Clipboard)
Start "http..."=$text
```

I click on my shortcut and it runs -- but only once.

After that, the Target rewrites itself to the following and stops working:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\myname\directory\search5.ps1
```

Is there any way to stop it from doing this? Why is it doing this?

Comment: Have you checked the target after you create the shortcut? It would resolve the items mentioned to its original paths as recorded in the environment variables of your system. I tested this and it did not stop working for me. What do you mean by that, does it give you error or do something else?

Comment: I create the shortcut, change the target, run the shortcut (and it works), check the target (it has changed), run the shortcut and I get a blank console screen.

Comment: I tried this with both the -File parameter and the -Command parameter and no problems with either. In either case the target automatically rewrites itself as soon as you save it. So it has nothing to do with running the program. Something weird is going on with your system.  What version of Windows, standalone or networked, domain or peer-to-peer?

Comment: My company uses Windows 10 Enterprise ver 1909. os build 18363.9 (64 bit operating).

Comment: What is `Get.Clipboard` ? The cmdlet's name is [Get-Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard), so that 2-line script should never work

Comment: Oops. That was a typo. I use Get-Clipboard. The shortcut is working now.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 paths are the same(the version in the path is always 1.0 regardless of the version you are running), that is why it is seemingly converting after running; try creating the same shortcut, but right click and look at the target before running.  For me at least, it converts it before I even run it.

My guess is it's the code itself causing the issue.  Try pointing the shortcut to a simple ps1 file that opens notepad by saving a powershell document that simply says "notepad" (sans quotes).  If you can run that multiple times without issue, then it is your code that you need to take a closer look at.

Comment: Thnx for the suggestion. I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Yes. Even before I run the shortcut it morphs to the v.1 path. I re-wrote the path from scratch and the shortcut is working. So it must have been something screwy with my system (I rebooted a second time this morning).